# Определение реального IP-адреса пользователя, использующего SOCKS-прокси

Tags: http, proxy, https, httpclient

Как определить реальный IP-адрес пользователя, который использует SOCKS-прокси и у которого выключены Flash и Java? Cookie тоже выключены - используется 1 окно в режиме инкогнито браузера Google Chrome последней версии.

Comment: А что есть реальный адрес? Если юзер сидит через VPN, адрес «реальный»?

Comment: @VladD  логично же что ip его первого провайдера) с которого он подключается к vpn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Технология webRTC позволяет это сделать.

Comment: [Да](https://ru.wikinews.org/wiki/WebRTC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81), уже установил у себя false для media.peerconnection.enabled

Answer (score 6):

Никак.
Реальным является адрес выхода, то есть если используется socks, то это будет адрес socks-сервера.

Comment: Поддерживаю, никак.

Comment: Голосую, но есть исключение) Есть такая штука https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%A0%D0%9C, она позволяет вычислить всё что нужно. Даже есть статьи по деанонимизации TOR...

Comment: Но простым смертным этим не воспользоваться

Comment: Silverlight не?

Comment: И чем он вам поможет? Я плохо представляю работу винды с прокси, но как я помню сильверлайт работает как компонент системы, так что если у вас в настройках браузера стоит использование socks, то никакого сильверлайта.

Comment: флеш дает возможность в обход прокси отправить данные. Силверлайт похожая технология которая может иметь доступ к системной инфе и возможно так же как и флеш может установить соединения в обход настроек прокси которые указаны в браузере и в настройках системы.

Comment: Ну, боюсь что это будет зависеть от настроек системы. У меня вот VPN до амазона, а поверх него уже socks5 over ssh до сервера обратно во Франции. Вот какой вы адрес получите? По дефолту французский серверный, если умудритесь вырваться из носков то амазоновский. А мой реальный как?

Comment: Большинство ограничиваются одним сервером.Ну и ип подсоединения к прокси тоже лишним не будет, можно уже будет сделать вывод что используйте прокси. Хотя и узнать реальный ип действительно невозможно данном случаи.

Comment: @ЭргилОсин может проведем эксперимент я определю твой реальный ip?))